# How to compute GCD with a MILP?

Tags: arithmetic, linear-programming, gcd-and-lcm, mixed-integer-programming

How would one formulate a linear optimisation program that computes the Greatest Common Divisor (GCD) of a set of $n$ numbers $\{a_1,...,a_n \}$?

I can only think of a non linear formulation :

$$
\max\;  \{ p \} 
$$
subject to
\begin{align*}
a_i &= p \cdot q_i \quad &\forall i=1,...,n\\
q_i &\in \mathbb{N} \quad &\forall i=1,...,n\\
p &\in \mathbb{N}
\end{align*}

One could linearize the product, but I am wondering if there is a better way to this (with an optimization program).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m = \min_{i \in \{1,\dots,n\}} a_i$.  For $p\in\{1,\dots,m\}$, let binary variable $z_p$ indicate whether $p$ is the GCD.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{p=1}^m p\ z_p$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{p=1}^m z_p &= 1 \\
(a_i-p\ a_i)(1 - z_p) \le a_i - p\ q_i &\le a_i (1 - z_p) &&\text{for $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$} \\
q_i &\in [0,a_i] \cap \mathbb{N} &&\text{for $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$}\\
z_p &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for $p \in \{1,\dots,m\}$}\\
\end{align}